# What do I need to provide in MessageRequest of the Converstation service to answer the first step in the conversation?

Tags: java, sdk, watson-conversation

I have a Conversation Service client in Java (using the SDK)

```
ConversationService conversationService = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_07_11, userName, password);
MessageRequest.Builder messageRequestBuilder = new MessageRequest.Builder();
messageRequestBuilder.inputText(question);
ServiceCall<MessageResponse> response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, messageRequestBuilder.build());
MessageResponse answer =  response.execute();
```

It does not matter what I provide as text, I always get the greetings message.
To get around this I perform a second call which includes the entire context from the answer, like this

```
messageRequestBuilder = new MessageRequest.Builder();
messageRequestBuilder.context(answer.getContext());
messageRequestBuilder.inputText(question);
response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, messsageRequestBuilder.build());
answer =  response.execute();
```

Now I do get past the initial greeting text.

My question is: what do I need to provide at the minimum in each step of the conversation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Watson Conversation service is stateless meaning that the state of the conversation is sent in `context` part of the JSON message request and response. So what you need to do is to get the `context` part from the JSON response of the Watson Conversation service and sent it back in the next request to the service including it in the message request.

In the `context` there is the info which node was processed last and where will the next round of evaluation start.

Comment: So I always need everything from the context ? Is it wise to add objects to the context from the client, or should this always be part of the input ?

Comment: You can add objects to the context from the client. This might make sense if you have some data about the user that is conversing with the system - e.g. his name or age. You can use this method to set these as variables in the `context` field and use them in the conversation flow. E.g. you add to `context`  `"username":"John"` and in the dialog node you write "Hi $username."...